# Allowing one radio button checked when radio inputs have different names

Tags: html, jquery, radio-button, checked

I'm trying to figure out how to only allow one of two radio buttons to be checked in a form where the two radio buttons don't share the same name. I've been experimenting for hours now, but can't figure it out. Here is what I have currently:

```js
$("#theForm").click(function(){
    //alert('You clicked radio!');
    if($('input:radio:checked')){
        $('input:radio:checked').prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="theForm">
    <form class="type">
        <input type="radio" id="topic" name="topic" value="on" checked>
        <input type="radio" id="all" name="all" value="on">
    </form>
</div>
```

Here's a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Codewalker/reh0mzs3/1/

Comment: Note that you do not need to include a separate fiddle - you can add your code as a runnable snippet directly in your question using the `[<>]` button in the editor (this is actually the preferred options because external links can change or be deleted over time)

Comment: Can you not have the radio buttons usng the same name? That is the correct usage of radio buttons and means you only need the default code. As well as needing more complex code, veering from the default can cause issues down the line.

Comment: The names are different on this form and post to separate fields in the database. There is a business and analytics reason for this, which is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: The specific reasons may be beyond the scope of the question, but whether or not it is possible the change them is very relevant and should be mentioned... otherwise you will get answers like the one below that make the assumption that they can be changed to the correct usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the click function will give you an event.  you can target the event.target.name to see which radio button was clicked on and then do a simple if statement to uncheck the other radio button

```js
$("#theForm").click(function(){           
    if(event.target.name == 'topic'){          
        $('#all').prop("checked", false);
    }else{
       $('#topic').prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="theForm">
    <form class="type">
        <input type="radio" id="topic" name="topic" value="on" checked>
        <input type="radio" id="all" name="all" value="on">
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<div> <input type="radio" id="contactChoice1" name="contact" value="email">
<label for="contactChoice1">Email</label>

<input type="radio" id="contactChoice2" name="contact" value="phone">
<label for="contactChoice2">Phone</label>

<input type="radio" id="contactChoice3" name="contact" value="message">
<label for="contactChoice3">Message</label> </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue. Answers should also address the problem that the question asked i.e. how to do when the *radio buttons have different names*. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).